# Show a loading bar similar to a browser's loading animation

Tags: php, css, browser

How can I give a feedback to the users by showing a loading bar, similar to what browser displays on the place of favicon.

The thing is, I am not using a javascript or ajax, I am calling an API, which will take time to load, I just want to give feedback to user by showing a loading bar, which will stop as soon as the page is finished loading.

In straight words, I want to exactly show what the browser shows - a loading animation, but this loading animation should be in the page, so that the user will know what is going on.

How can I do this? I am using PHP in the backend

Comment: Why can't you use javascript? The best ways to achieve this is with javascript and I'm not sure if it's possible to do this without it. With javascript you can hide an animated image after the website is loaded or jump to another website with the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a preloader. Check out [this tutorial](http://techsini.com/how-to-add-css-preloader-to-your-website-tutorial/) to see the exact code to accomplish it. Essentially you're creating a large overlay in HTML/CSS that will disappear when the JS code detects the page is finished loading.